# How to resize Spyder IDE window?

Tags: windows-10, python, ide

I want to resize Spyder window to half of window but its not resizing to half , also want to resize variable explorer window much right i.e. much right whenever I can change anywhere at right so that I have editor window whatever size I want, so how to do it ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to shrink the windows like you wanted.  I also wanted to do the same.

What you can do is go into the View dropdown and switch the Window Layouts.  The Horizontal split layout gives you the entire width and leaves the console on the bottom which you can greatly minimize.